# Magento 2: How to get order from Customer Id

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, orders, customer

I'm learning `Magento 2` and got a headache while trying to find how to get all orders from customer.

With `Magento 1.x`, we can get all orders from customer with the below code.

```
$yourCustomerId = '123123';
$field = 'customer_id';
$collection = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addFieldToFilter($field, $yourCustomerId);
```

Anyone out there can please show me the correct way in 2.x version?

UPDATED:

I want to get the orders from customer (`Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer`) event observer.

Comment: Where you tried to call this code?

Comment: @AmitBera I've just edit the question. Please take a look.

Answer (score 10):

As per as,magento2 standard,At `__construct()` function of yours `block class/model class/Controller` class you need to inject Sales Collection Factory class,**Then Filter that collection by Customer id**.

```
protected $_orderCollectionFactory;
protected $orders;
public function __construct(
    .....
            \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
           .......
        ) {
    ...
    $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    ........
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}


public function getOrders()
{

    if (!$this->orders) {
        $this->orders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect(
            '*'
        )->addFieldToFilter(
            'customer_id',
            $customerId
        )->setOrder(
            'created_at',
            'desc'
        );
    }
    return $this->orders;
}
```

if you try to use this at block clals then at  *your block class's phtml file* ,you can call  the Order collection by `$orderCollection = $block->getOrders();`

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without using `\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory` ? Can we just simple use the Order model? I want to get orders from customer (`Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer`) event observer.

Comment: wait,you will reply you

Comment: Doesn't the __construct is missing context and a data-array?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory`, we can use Magento's `SearchCriteriaBuilder` to get the order data by customer id with optimized code.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\ViewModel;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class MyClass implements ArgumentInterface
{
    /**
     * @var OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $orderRepository;
    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
    ) {
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * @param $customerId
     */
    public function getOrderDataByCustomerId($customerId)
    {
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('customer_id', $customerId, 'eq')->create();
        $orders = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
    }
    
    /**
     * @param $orderIds
     */
    public function getOrderDataByOrderIds($orderIds)
    {
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $orderIds])->create();
        $orders = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
    }
}
```

Hope it will simplify the approach for getting order data. :)