# Control customer who bought can write review

Tags: magento2, review

I want to accept customer who purchases can fill on review form. If a customer doesn't buy it, it'll show a notification that you must buy it before writing review. Can you help me how to work? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I can give you a brief idea.

You would need to put condition in the review form.

Put below conditions before  code:

- Whether a customer is logged in or not
- If customer is logged in, then check whether customer has ordered the same product SKU or not.

Please let me know if you have any query.

Update: To check whether customer is logged in or not, try below code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   // customer login action
}
```

For getting order from customer id, please follow below link:

> [How to get order from customer Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110481/how-to-get-order-from-customer-magento-2)

Comment: Can you tell me, how to work it. I have a form, but I don't know to check customer. If you have any sample code, that's great. Thanks