# Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted

Tags: magento2

I running the following code

```
  class MyOrders extends AbstractCollection implements MyOrdersInterface{

public function _construct(){
    $this->_init('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order', 'Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order');
}

/**
* @api
* @param int $customerId
* @return array
*/
  public function getOrders($customerId){
    //if (!$this->orders) {
        $orders = $this->create()->addFieldToSelect(
            '*'
        )->addFieldToFilter(
            'customer_id',
            $customerId
        )->setOrder(
            'created_at',
            'desc'
        );
    //}
    //$ordersCollection = $this->addAttributeToFilter("customer_id", $customerId)->load();

    $a=array($orders);
    return $a;
}
}
```

but xampp error log gives me the following error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted (tried to 
allocate 387989504 bytes) in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\yourParts\\app\\code\\Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Collection\\AbstractCollection.php on line 246
```

I've changed memory_limit = -1 in php.ini but it doesn't work

Comment: What is `MyOrdersInterface` ? You should try using the Order collection factory like this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/110483/2671

Comment: @DanCarlyon that's Interface I've made

Answer (score 1):

Add this: `ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');` to `app/bootstrap.php`.

I would recommend changing it back after you finish with your tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check below code to get order collection filter by Customer ID.

```
public function __construct(
         \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory){
  $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
}

public function getOrders($customerId){
{

 $collection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create();
 $collection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', array('eq'=>$customerId))
         ->addAttributeToSort('created_at','DESC')
         ->getItems();
 return $collection;

}
```