# Convert M1 code to M2 code

Tags: magento2, sales-order

Here this is the Magento 1 code would like to convert to M2 code.

```
$customerId = 1;
$orderCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
        ->addFieldToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId)
        ->addFieldToFilter('state', array('in' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getVisibleOnFrontStates()))
        ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');
```

Here mainly need to know how to add `->addFieldToFilter('state', array('in' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getVisibleOnFrontStates()))` statement in Magento2

Thanks

Comment: Please check this one - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110481/how-to-get-order-from-customer-magento-2

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but what about `getVisibleOnFrontStates` filter? do you have any idea @AnasMansuri

Comment: after collection use visible_on_front

Answer (score 2):

You can find the reference in this class Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History

```
class Orders
{
    protected $_customerSession;

    protected $_orderConfig;

    private $_orderCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $_orderCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config $orderConfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
         $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $_orderCollectionFactory;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_orderConfig = $orderConfig;
    }

   public function getOrders()
   {
    $orders = null;
        if (!($customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId())) {
            return false;
        }

    $orders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $orders->addFieldToFilter("customer_id", $customerId);
        $orders->addFieldToSelect(
                '*'
        )->addFieldToFilter(
            'status',
            ['in' => $this->_orderConfig->getVisibleOnFrontStatuses()]
        )->setOrder(
           'created_at',
           'desc'
        );
        return $orders;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

in constructor:

```
protected $orderCollectionFactory;
public function __construct(
...
\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
...
){
    $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
}
```

Then in any of your function you can use this:

```
$collection = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addFieldToFilter("customer_id", $customerId);
```

where `$this->orderCollectionFactory` is the instance of `\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory`

You can add more filters to it

Comment: thanks @shoaibmunir would like to know >addFieldToFilter('state', array('in' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getVisibleOnFrontStates()))

Comment: `getVisibleOnFrontStates` is used for the comments that are only visible on frontend. Like you can add multiple comments on admin order but it wont visible on frontend, but when you check "Visible on Frontend" before adding comments to order, then it would visible on frontend

Comment: You don't need to add this filter in order collection, state of order is somethings else. and `visible_on_frontend` is only for comments

Answer (score 1):

You can try once below code,

```
protected $_orderCollectionFactory;
protected $orders;
protected $_salesConfig;
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory 
$orderCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config $salesConfig
    ) {
   $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
   $this->_salesConfig = $salesConfig;
   parent::__construct($context, $data);
}


 public function getOrderCollection()
 {

if (!$this->orders) {
    $this->orders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect(
        '*'
    )->addFieldToFilter(
        'customer_id',
        $customerId
    )->addFieldToFilter('state', array('in' => $this->_salesConfig->getVisibleOnFrontStatuses()))
    ->setOrder(
        'created_at',
        'desc'
     );
 }
  return $this->orders;

 }
```

**Hope this will help in your case!!**

Comment: thanks let me check